# How to build libraries with different options for different CMake targets?

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake project which consist from a set libraries. 
This libraries links with a several programs.

Is it possible to replace compile options, for libraries which build for specifical programs?

For example, when cmake builds library for program A it defines first includes directory, for another program it includes directory B?

Comment: Yes, but it may be easier to put this logic in the `CMakeLists.txt` of the two programs rather than the library. The library should not know which program is going to build it.

Comment: Thanks for reply!

Could you advise the best way to do this?

How to get the CMake to assemble a different set of libraries?
Now I just use the commands `add_subdirectory`/`add_library`. 

What should I change in my project?